# Tensorflow Benchmarks Input Pipeline Parallelize Image Processing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, tfrecord

I'm running the TF [benchmarks](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks) and have read the document [High-Performance Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models), I have a question:

In the document, it said

> Parallelize I/O Reads
>
> data_flow_ops.RecordInput is used to parallelize reading from disk. Given a list of input files representing TFRecords, RecordInput continuously reads records using background threads. The records are placed into its own large internal pool and when it has loaded at least half of its capacity, it produces output tensors.
>
> This op has its own internal threads that are dominated by I/O time that consume minimal CPU, which allows it to run smoothly in parallel with the rest of the model.
>
> Parallelize Image Processing
>
> After images are read from RecordInput they are passed as tensors to the image processing pipeline. To make the image processing pipeline easier to explain, assume that the input pipeline is targeting 8 GPUs with a batch size of 256 (32 per GPU).
>
> 256 records are read and processed individually in parallel. This starts with 256 independent RecordInput read ops in the graph. Each read op is followed by an identical set of ops for image preprocessing that are considered independent and executed in parallel. The image preprocessing ops include operations such as image decoding, distortion, and resizing.

But I read the code of [preprocessing.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/preprocessing.py)

```
        record_input = data_flow_ops.RecordInput(
        file_pattern=dataset.tf_record_pattern(subset),
        seed=301,
        parallelism=64,
        buffer_size=10000,
        batch_size=self.batch_size,
        shift_ratio=shift_ratio,
        name='record_input')
    records = record_input.get_yield_op()
    records = tf.split(records, self.batch_size, 0)
    records = [tf.reshape(record, []) for record in records]
    for idx in xrange(self.batch_size):
      value = records[idx]
      (label, image) = self.parse_and_preprocess(value, idx)
      split_index = idx % self.num_splits
      labels[split_index].append(label)
      images[split_index].append(image)
```

It seems reading from disk in parallel due to `data_flow_ops.RecordInput` op,
but image processing ops in the for loop is serialized.

I want to know I am wrong or document is wrong?
If I am wrong, how do image processing ops execute in parallel?
Thanks very much!